# polynomial representation of $sl_{2}(k)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraic closed field of characteristic 0. We write

$$X=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right),~~
Y=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right),~~
H=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Consider the polynomial representation of $sl_{2}(k)$,
$$\rho:sl_{2}(k)\rightarrow End(k[x,y]),~~
\rho(X)=x\frac{\partial}{\partial
y},~~\rho(Y)=y\frac{\partial}{\partial
x},~~\rho(H)=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial
y}$$. Then:

1. The universal enveloping algebra $U(sl_{2}(k))$ is generated by
   the set {$\rho(X),~\rho(Y),~\rho(H)$} as an algebra.
2. We write $L=sl_{2}(k)$.

$k[x,y]$ can be written as the direct sum of finite dimensional
simple modules:

$k[x,y]=\displaystyle{\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} k[x,y]_{n}}$.

Moreover, if $M$ is a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $sl_{2}(k)$ with $dim(M)=n+1$, then $M\cong k[x,y]_{n}$ as $L$-modules.
Can we extend this result to some kinds of Lie algebras?

Specifically, I try to find a class $\mathfrak{L}$ of Lie algebras,
such that $\forall L\in\mathfrak{L}$, there is an $L$-module $V$
("polynomial representation of $L$") possessing the following
properties:

1. The universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$ is generated by some
   "differential operators of $V$" as an algebra.
2. $V$ can be written as a direct sum of simple modules:
   $V=\displaystyle{\bigoplus_{i\in \Lambda} V_{i}}$. Moreover, if $M$
   is a simple $L$-module, there exists $i\in \Lambda$ such that
   $M\cong V_{i}$ as $L$-modules.

Comment: I get into trouble when I type the $2\times 2$ matrices $X$, $Y$ and $H$. Can somebody help me to edit it?

Comment: @John Wiltshire-Gordon: Thanks you!